# javascript function expression versus classes

Tags: javascript, selenium

So i'm trying to learn some javascript together with Selenium. I've read a few examples and i see two types of approaches to implement the page object model.

first way:

```
class Page {
    constructor() {
        const { Builder, By, Key, until, Capabilities } = require('selenium-webdriver');
        let chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
        let dockerHub = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";
        let options = new chrome.Options();

        this.driver = new Builder()
            .forBrowser("chrome")
            .usingServer(dockerHub)
            .build();
    }
    open(url) {
        return this.driver.get(url);
    }
    quit() {
        console.log("shutting down driver...")
        return this.driver.quit();
    }
}
```

second way:

```
const { Builder, By, Key, until, Capabilities } = require('selenium-webdriver');
let chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
let dockerHub = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";
let options = new chrome.Options();

var Page = function () {
    this.driver = new Builder()
        .forBrowser("chrome")
        .usingServer(dockerhub)
        .build();
    var driver = this.driver;

    this.open = function (url) {
        return driver.get(url);
    }
    this.quit = function () {
        console.log("shutting down driver...")
        return driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Coming from Java i feel the first approach is more correct. But in the examples i've read the second approach is way more common. So i'm wondering whats the benefits of doing a function expression over a class?

Comment: Well, for one thing, I can `Page = null` to destroy the reference to that anonymous function, thus making it potentially available for garbage collecting.

Comment: Coming from Java though, you may be aware that Java also has closures.  There are multiple ways in Java to declare methods as well.

Comment: @Taplar Yes but i don't understand why it seems to be the preferred choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript has not always had formal classes. Some JS runtimes still don't support classes. One likely reason you see less use of classes in legacy code is that it was written in a different era. But that's just a historical explanation.

As far as pros v cons of each, one benefit of using classes is that you get formal lifecycle methods. If that's a good fit for your needs, then use classes. But you can implement the same API and functionality using either paradigm.

Remember that the most important job of code is to be understood by developers. One thing that is nice about the functional approach is that it doesn't require additional knowledge of how classes work. Coming from a Java background, it may surprise you to learn that not all developers are familiar or comfortable with classical OO patterns. If I were working with a bunch of JS devs who were not comfortable with class-oriented patterns, I would hesitate to use classes.

One is not more correct than the other. Historically, classes have not been idiomatic javascript because they literally didn't exist. That idiom will probably change as runtime support for classes spreads and developers get comfortable with OO patterns.